# Native crashes on some devices with ProGuard

Tags: android, crash, android-proguard

EDIT: For future devs who may be suffering from the same issues, I'm afraid I can't be of much use. The problem apparently solved itself during future versions of the app, but I have been unable to ascertain the cause.

I've been testing an application through the Google Play closed beta testing system, using my friends as beta testers. After pushing an update where the .apk was obfuscated using ProGuard, two testers started reporting crashes. The crashes are unpredictable and sporadic, and they have been unable to ascertain any reason or pattern for them. To make things worse, the crash reports I'm getting in the Dev Console contain no information at all, simply stating "Native crash at (no location available)", no stack trace, not even any device information.

I do know the device information through just asking the testers in question, and both devices are Sony phones, an Xperia Z3 and an Xperia Z3 Compact. However, I also have a Z3 Compact available for testing and have been unable to reproduce the crash while running the same obfuscated apk. We are running the same OS version as well.

I have sent one of the testers and unobfuscated apk, and he was unable to reproduce the crash running that version. This, and the fact that the crash first occurred after a patch that introduced ProGuard obfuscation, leads me to believe that to be the cause.

At first, I ran ProGuard using only the default configuration file from the SDK:

```
# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# LINK REMOVED

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
# Note that if you want to enable optimization, you cannot just
# include optimization flags in your own project configuration file;
# instead you will need to point to the
# "proguard-android-optimize.txt" file instead of this one from your
# project.properties file.

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see LINK REMOVED
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**
```

I have since added the following lines to proguard-project.txt, which is also included in the proguard configuration variable for the project:

```
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected java.lang.Object[][] getContents();
}

# Keep SafeParcelable value, needed for reflection. This is required to support backwards
# compatibility of some classes.
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

# Keep the names of classes/members we need for client functionality.
-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

# Needed for Parcelable/SafeParcelable Creators to not get stripped
-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}

# Needed when building against the Marshmallow SDK
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**

# Needed when building against pre-Marshmallow SDK.
-dontwarn android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-libraryjars D:/Docs/Android/spaceprog/spaceprogr/libs/android-support-v4.jar
-keep class com.viewpagerindicator.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.example.games.basegameutils.** { *; }
-printmapping out.map
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

The upper part (with comments) of these additions comes directly from the README of the Google Play Services as a recommendation to be added whenever using the library. The rest I added myself while trying to research and debug the problem.

If anyone notices any omissions or other signs of trouble in my ProGuard configuration I'd be happy to know. I'd also be greatful for any suggestions on how to further debug the problem. Keep in mind that full module testing where only one module is obfuscated at a time is impossible in this case, because I do not have a device that can reproduce the issue and I cannot ask volunteer testers to install 30+ different versions of the .apk and play until it either crashes or until they are confident it will not.